# Custom language resolver location to have available Tracker information

Tags: multilingual, geo-location

I want to change the website language based on the geo ip data based on this article:
https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/05/sitecore-context-language-geo-ip-location.html

I added my custom language processor like this and add necessarily code to get the country and set a new context language:

```
<startAnalytics>
   <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking, Sitecore.Analytics']" type="your-language-resolver, .." />
</startAnalytics>
```

**Issues**:

- If my custom processor derives from RenderLayoutProcessor then the code isn't executed.
- If I don't derives then code is executed but Sitecore.Context.Language still not changed when open the website.

I'm not able to figure which is the best place to change the language and also have Tracker information about country available.

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you on?

Comment: Sitecore.NET 9.0.0 (rev. 171002)

Comment: I think `renderLayout` is now for aspx pages only. Better check "mvc.render..." pipelines

Comment: Has anybody got solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Founded the solution. Custom language resolver should be added into *mvc.requestBegin*, here we have all information about Tracker.

```
<pipelines>
        <mvc.requestBegin>
            <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.MvcEvents.RequestBegin.StartTracking, Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics']" 
                       type="your-language-resolver ..."  />
        </mvc.requestBegin>
    </pipelines>
```